# My code is printing a new line in front of the output

Tags: java, printing, output, newline

I'm writing a code and I got a problem, my code is printing a new line in front of the output. I want to avoid that.

Here is my code

```
                if (movieName.length() > 44)
                {
                    movieName = movieName.substring(0, 44);
                }
                
                if(frqName.equals(movieName) && frqRating.equals(movieRating)) 
                {
                    
                    System.out.print(" " + movieTime);
                    
                }
                    
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf("%-44s | %5s | %s", movieName, movieRating, movieTime);
                    
                }
                
                frqName = movieName;
                frqRating = movieRating;

            }
        
        }
        
    }
```

and here is my output — with the undesired empty line first:

```
Wonders of the World                         |     G | 16:40 20:00
Journey to Space                             | PG-13 | 19:00
Buffalo Bill And The Indians or Sitting Bull |    PG | 12:45 15:00 19:30
Adventure of Lewis and Clark                 | PG-13 | 10:00 14:30
Halloween                                    |     R | 19:00
```

I think the problem is from the first print statement; but how do I fix it properly?

I already tried deleting `System.out.println();` from the `else` part and appending a newline to the format string in the following line. But then the further show times for the same move are printing on the following line, which is still worse.

Comment: But this line is the problem: System.out.println(); This is make the new line.

Comment: What do you mean with the output getting messed up?

Comment: I tried removing it as I said but the output got messed up like times will go in different lines

Comment: Two ways come to mind: First the nice and manageable way. Get hold of your data. Make a complete list of show times for each movie before printing anything. This will allow you to print movie title, rating and times on one line and a newline at the end. You may use a `Movie` object containing a list of show times or a `Map<Movie, List<LocalTime>>` or similar. –

Comment: – Second the algorithmic approach: I assume you are doing this in a loop. Print the first movie (with no newline) before the loop and set `frqName` and `frqRating` correspondingly. Keep your code in the loop as it is. Add a `System.out.println()` after the loop to terminate the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
if (frqName.equals(movieName) && frqRating.equals(movieRating)) {
    System.out.println(" " + movieTime);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%-44s | %5s | %s \n", movieName, movieRating, movieTime);
}
```

… and your output will not begin with an empty line.

I would also (although I don't know your intentions) remove the `" " +` before `movieTime` in the new `System.out.println()`

```
System.out.println(movieTime);
```

Comment: I tried that but the output times got in different lanes

Comment: Then just add `%n` or `\n` (`n` for *new line*) into the `System.out.printf()`

Comment: I tried that also but got the same thing, I edited the post to show the full code I think the problem is caused by another print statement but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: If `frqName.equals(movieName) && frqRating.equals(movieRating)` arrives, then you only print `System.out.print(" " + movieTime);`. Because there is a `...print()` and no `...println()` the `movieTime` from this movie will printing to the end of the line from the previous movie. Add there a `System.out.println(" " + movieTime);`!